Is it likely these VL53L0X IC's sold on aliexpress are counterfeit or stolen?
I am fairly new to electronics and am wondering about how counterfeiting versus grey-market reselling in china works for something like a TOF Lidar sensor such as the VL53L0X made by ST microelectronics.  I was under the impression that the VL53L0X is a fairly sophisticated device, having a "leading-edge SPAD array (single photon avalanche diodes) and ST’s second generation FlightSense patented technology".
From the reviews on Amazon the parts seem to work reasonably well for hobbyists, but judging by the prices on Aliexpress (where everything on Amazon comes from), they are likely counterfeit or greymarket. See this figure I have made where we have Aliexpress, Amazon in the top row, and ST microelectronics and Adafruit on the bottom row.  
Naively I would think something like this is difficult to fake and if it were faked it would be obvious to STM and the authorities who would have the capabilities to do so.  Is it more likely that they are NOT FAKE but rather greymarket/ stolen ,or  diverted goods- possibly devices made on a manufacturing line that were later stored improperly or didn't meet certain stringent QC requirements for sale from somewhere reputable?.
I do see that the country of origin for this IC is indeed China.

Parts that failed QC, parts that were removed from PCBA, ghost shifts, stolen wafers, the options for fakes are endless.

I don't think we can give an answer like a number with some tolerance how likely it is that the parts you are looking at are stolen, counterfeit, factory rejects, salvaged or refurbished. We also don't understand how the market can work. For example, there might be a batch of components going stale due to shelf life, so they cannot sell them to customers. The batch could be just dumped to market with a low price and some other party buys it and makes hobbyist grade boards with the components that could have otherwise been costly to recycle or get rid of.

Does it really matter to you whether these are parts that failed QC, second-hand parts, or clones? In practice, all you can be certain of is that the specs in ST's datasheet don't necessarily apply to these parts, so using them is a hit or miss. Nobody is going to tell you how exactly these ICs deviate from the spec; not even the seller likely knows, each individual part might deviate in a different way.

Aliexpress is an independent platform from Amazon, though there may be sellers who operate on both. Amazon both sells for themselves and provides a platform for 3rd party sellers (with or without fulfillment). Aliexpress (international B2C) and their big brother Alibaba (international B2B) don't actually sell for themselves AFAIK, they only provide a platform (including some services such as escrow and consolidation).
Price of VL53L0X chips in China from independent sellers seems to be in the 50-cent (USD) to $2.00 range in tape and reel. The cheaper ones seem to have different markings and the sellers are not mentioning ST, just the part number, so I suspect it's been cloned. Generally there is more accountability in domestic sales since the product can be easily and cheaply returned (a couple dollars with full tracking).
